# When does a Riemaniann metric form a coercive quadratic form?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let

$
A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  g^{11} & g^{12} & \cdots & 0& 0 \\
  g^{21} & g^{22} & \cdots & 0&0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots &1 &  0\\
  0 & 0 & \cdots&0&  1
 \end{pmatrix}$\

where $g^{ij}$ are the components of the inverse of a Riemannian metric $g_{ij}$

Given $\Phi=(\phi_{1},\phi_{2}....\phi_{n},\phi)$ where $\phi_{m}=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x^{m}}$ is the "energy" defined as:

$$E=\int\Phi^{T}A\Phi$$

Is $E$ a coercive quadratic form (i.e.,$\int\Phi^{T}A\Phi\ge\int\mu\Phi^{T}\Phi$ for $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ )?

If not, which are the geometrical conditions on $g_{ij}$ such that this is satisfied?

This question arises from the fact that this is a key condition in symmetric hyperbolic systems in order to prove energy inequalities. Also, I am aware that second order linear wave equations can be rewritten as first order systems.

However, it is not clear to me that this "energy" is coercive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Riemannian metric (or its "inverse" metric) is **by definition** a positive definite quadratic form. In finite dimensions this immediately guarantees that the eigenvalues have a lower bound and that the form is coercive. There is nothing to prove here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is the result also true, if the coefficients have lower regularity?

Comment: You are asking about a pointwise bound. What does regularity have to do with it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry. I realized I miss a bunch  of integrals. Why is zero not a possible eigenvalue?

Comment: Because a Riemannian metric is by definition positive definite and positive definite matrices do not have zero as a eigenvalue, again by definition?